# Angular material - Manual input incorrectly converts date

Tags: angular, angular-material

ive set the locale of the date to be en-GB - so that the datepicker can be in the UK format.

If i enter a date manually `10/12/2018` (10th December 2018)  and hit tab the date gets converted to `12/10/2018` (12th October 2018) .

Selecting the original date using the picker works fine this problem only occurs when typing it in manually and when specifying a locale.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv6jny

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

--

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
  ]
```

Is this a bug with the datepicker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a bug. You need to build a custom date adapter like this:

```
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

    parse(value: any): Date | null {

    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
       const str = value.split('/');

      const year = Number(str[2]);
      const month = Number(str[1]) - 1;
      const date = Number(str[0]);

      return new Date(year, month, date);
    }
    const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
    return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
  }

  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    date = new Date(Date.UTC(
      date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(),
      date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds()));
    displayFormat = Object.assign({}, displayFormat, { timeZone: 'utc' });

    const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(this.locale, displayFormat);
    return dtf.format(date).replace(/[\u200e\u200f]/g, '');
  }

}
```

and then use it in your app:

```
@NgModule({
    ....
    provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter }
})
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv6jny-ynqfb2)

Comment: This solution works fine but when an incorrect date is entered manually let's say like: 1/1/1, it gets formatted to a valid date instead of showing an error. Please help me on this to ensure that when an invalid date is entered, the date field is marked red to indicate an error.

Answer (score 0):

To support other locales, that use dots in stead of slashes, you can also use the moment dateadapter and formats. Moment supports this functionality out of the box.

```
npm install moment @angular/material-moment-adapter --save
```

app.module.ts

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
    },
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
      useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS
    }
  ],
```

Comment: where do you set the locale?

Comment: @F.H. My comment just replaces the default date parser with the moment date parser. The locale can be set like this (just search for locale) describedhttps://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview