# Angular material manual date update for datepicker not working correctly

Tags: angular, validation, mat-datepicker, mat-input

I am using angular material dateipcker in my application to map the selected date in input box with dd/MM/yyyy format. But in the input field if we enter the dateformat in dd/MM/yyyy it is throwing an error as it seems it is taking format as MM/dd/yyyy for validation.

Kindly help me to fix this issue. Below is my code

**html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**app.module.ts file**

```
providers:[ {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}]
```

When we click on datpicker icon it is working fine and when we try to enter it manually from input field it is throwing an error.

**Current senario** **click on datepicker**

[image]

**Tried to modify manually**

[image]

Comment: I hope this will resolve your issue. Please go through this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755818/angular-material-manual-input-incorrectly-converts-date